# Start up errors with Oracle Weblogic Server plugin for Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, oracle, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-luna

We have an existing project which we built using Eclipse Indigo and the relevant weblogic server plugin. This was done four years back and we are trying to migrate to the Eclipse Luna. The project imports and everything works fine until I add the weblogic server tools plugin for Eclipse Luna or a lower version and restart eclipse. It starts complaining "An internal error occurred during"

- Building Workspace
- Initializing Java Tooling
- Validating project
- AppXray Indexing (This I could fix by disabling from Windows->Preferences->Oracle->AppXray)

The resulting application EAR is deployed on Oracle Weblogic Server 10gR3.
Any help with resolving the issues will be highly appreciated. I know the problem is with the Oracle Weblogic Server tool plugin for Eclipse Luna as the moment I remove it I do not see any errors. I have tried cleaning up .metadata and then relaunching eclipse but still the error starts ocurring.

**UPDATE**: Below is the exception stacktrace that I found from the .log file within .metadata. I am not able to understand anything from the log. Can anyone help?

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2015-04-29 07:07:17.086
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Java Tooling".
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: IModuleReferenceSystemLibrary.ResolvedPath:     ResolvedPathDerivedValueService.compute() has failed
at org.eclipse.sapphire.services.DataService.refresh(DataService.java:130)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.services.DataService.data(DataService.java:75)
at     org.eclipse.sapphire.DerivedValueService.value(DerivedValueService.java:34)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.Value.refreshContent(Value.java:119)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.Value.refreshContent(Value.java:83)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.Value.text(Value.java:260)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.Value.text(Value.java:253)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.syslib.internal.SystemLibrariesContainerImpl.createContainer(SystemLibrariesContainerImpl.java:200)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.syslib.internal.SystemLibrariesContainerImpl$Initializer.initialize(SystemLibrariesContainerImpl.java:278)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2902)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$9.run(JavaModelManager.java:2808)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2313)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeAllContainers(JavaModelManager.java:2848)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1932)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.initializeAfterLoad(JavaCore.java:4016)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.InitializeAfterLoadJob$RealJob.run(InitializeAfterLoadJob.java:36)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: IModuleReferenceSystemLibrary.ModuleId: PossibleValuesValidationService.compute() has failed
at org.eclipse.sapphire.services.DataService.refresh(DataService.java:130)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.services.DataService.data(DataService.java:75)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.services.ValidationService.validation(ValidationService.java:49)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.Property.refreshValidation(Property.java:254)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.Property.validation(Property.java:476)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.syslib.internal.ModuleReferenceSystemLibraryServices$ResolvedPathDerivedValueService.compute(ModuleReferenceSystemLibraryServices.java:74)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.syslib.internal.ModuleReferenceSystemLibraryServices$ResolvedPathDerivedValueService.compute(ModuleReferenceSystemLibraryServices.java:1)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.services.DataService.refresh(DataService.java:103)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: IModuleReferenceSystemLibrary.ModuleId: ModuleIdValuesProvider.compute() has failed
at org.eclipse.sapphire.services.DataService.refresh(DataService.java:130)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.services.DataService.data(DataService.java:75)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.PossibleValuesService.values(PossibleValuesService.java:77)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.services.internal.PossibleValuesValidationService.compute(PossibleValuesValidationService.java:57)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.services.internal.PossibleValuesValidationService.compute(PossibleValuesValidationService.java:1)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.services.DataService.refresh(DataService.java:103)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.util.DomUtil.elements(DomUtil.java:152)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.WebLogicServerInstall.parseFeatureXmlFile(WebLogicServerInstall.java:490)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.WebLogicServerInstall.loadModulesRegistry(WebLogicServerInstall.java:477)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.WebLogicServerInstall.getModules(WebLogicServerInstall.java:394)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.syslib.internal.ModuleIdValuesProvider.compute(ModuleIdValuesProvider.java:22)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.PossibleValuesService.compute(PossibleValuesService.java:93)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.PossibleValuesService.compute(PossibleValuesService.java:1)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.services.DataService.refresh(DataService.java:103)
... 28 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2015-04-29 07:07:17.274
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: IModuleReferenceSystemLibrary.ResolvedPath: ResolvedPathDerivedValueService.compute() has failed
at org.eclipse.sapphire.services.DataService.refresh(DataService.java:130)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.services.DataService.data(DataService.java:75)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.DerivedValueService.value(DerivedValueService.java:34)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.Value.refreshContent(Value.java:119)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.Value.refreshContent(Value.java:83)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.Value.text(Value.java:260)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.Value.text(Value.java:253)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.syslib.internal.SystemLibrariesContainerImpl.createContainer(SystemLibrariesContainerImpl.java:200)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.syslib.internal.SystemLibrariesContainerImpl$Initializer.initialize(SystemLibrariesContainerImpl.java:278)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2902)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$9.run(JavaModelManager.java:2808)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2313)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeAllContainers(JavaModelManager.java:2848)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1932)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainer(JavaCore.java:3247)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2693)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2857)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:1962)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.isOnClasspath(JavaProject.java:2240)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.BuildpathIndicatorLabelDecorator.getOverlay(BuildpathIndicatorLabelDecorator.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.BuildpathIndicatorLabelDecorator.decorate(BuildpathIndicatorLabelDecorator.java:35)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorDefinition.decorate(LightweightDecoratorDefinition.java:273)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager$LightweightRunnable.run(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:83)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager.decorate(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:367)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager.getDecorations(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:349)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$1.ensureResultCached(DecorationScheduler.java:372)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$1.run(DecorationScheduler.java:332)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: IModuleReferenceSystemLibrary.ModuleId: PossibleValuesValidationService.compute() has failed
at org.eclipse.sapphire.services.DataService.refresh(DataService.java:130)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.services.DataService.data(DataService.java:75)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.services.ValidationService.validation(ValidationService.java:49)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.Property.refreshValidation(Property.java:254)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.Property.validation(Property.java:476)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.syslib.internal.ModuleReferenceSystemLibraryServices$ResolvedPathDerivedValueService.compute(ModuleReferenceSystemLibraryServices.java:74)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.syslib.internal.ModuleReferenceSystemLibraryServices$ResolvedPathDerivedValueService.compute(ModuleReferenceSystemLibraryServices.java:1)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.services.DataService.refresh(DataService.java:103)
... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: IModuleReferenceSystemLibrary.ModuleId: ModuleIdValuesProvider.compute() has failed
at org.eclipse.sapphire.services.DataService.refresh(DataService.java:130)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.services.DataService.data(DataService.java:75)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.PossibleValuesService.values(PossibleValuesService.java:77)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.services.internal.PossibleValuesValidationService.compute(PossibleValuesValidationService.java:57)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.services.internal.PossibleValuesValidationService.compute(PossibleValuesValidationService.java:1)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.services.DataService.refresh(DataService.java:103)
... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.util.DomUtil.elements(DomUtil.java:152)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.WebLogicServerInstall.parseFeatureXmlFile(WebLogicServerInstall.java:490)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.WebLogicServerInstall.loadModulesRegistry(WebLogicServerInstall.java:477)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.WebLogicServerInstall.getModules(WebLogicServerInstall.java:394)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.syslib.internal.ModuleIdValuesProvider.compute(ModuleIdValuesProvider.java:22)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.PossibleValuesService.compute(PossibleValuesService.java:93)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.PossibleValuesService.compute(PossibleValuesService.java:1)
at org.eclipse.sapphire.services.DataService.refresh(DataService.java:103)
... 40 more
```

Comment: Look for a more detailed error message in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory

Comment: have provided the log file content, can anybody help further on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experiencing this problem on our team I thought I would post the solution we found.

This occurred when we moved from a Luna based IDE to the Mars SR1 release.  We tracked it down to a file that was in source control.

`.settings/oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.syslib.xml`

Once deleted eclipse would start happily, and we were good to go.  One developer tracked the issue down to a single line inside the file.

`<module id="javax.persistence" javadoc="http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api"/>`

If that single <module>  line is commented out the eclipse oepe error goes away.  FYI, you won't see this error when importing the project, just on every restart after the project has been pulled down.

Comment: This could be the solution, did not face the issue after upgrading to Mars